# Dealing with blank folder names while using get-childitem in powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I built a script, that searches through all directories recursively with `Get-ChildItem`. The problem is, there exist directories with blank names (done with alt+255).

When the script encounters such a directory, it still lists the files in this directory, but does not search in its sub-directories.

Comment: Why don't you fix the directory names?

Comment: I would have done this. But I run this on a server and am not allowed to change anything.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that you are working for a company where an admin done this? I would advice him to change it or talk with your boss....

Comment: Tell the person who created blank named folders that they need to rename them, whoever came up with that idea is an idiot!

Comment: Can you show us the script?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in powershell. but you can skip to cmd and use

`cmd -c dir $Location /s`
that works!

Answer (score 0):

As @Bert Levrau mentioned above you can do a recursive search in CMD. Using `Get-ChildItem` in Powershell with a folder that has an ALT + 255 name will throw it into an infinite recursive loop. You can invoke a CMD process from Powershell though using the following example: `$result = cmd /c $directoryPath /s`

At that point, you can work through the result to find the information that you need.